# Output from web scraping with bs4 returns empty lists

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape specific information from a website of 25 pages but when I run my code i get empty lists. My output is supposed to be dictionary with the specific information scraped. Please any help would be appreciated.

```
# Loading libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import mitosheet

# Assigning column names using class_ names
name_selector = "af885_1iPzH"
old_price_selector = "f6eb3_1MyTu"
new_price_selector = "d7c0f_sJAqi"
discount_selector = "._6c244_q2qap"

# Placeholder list
data = []

# Looping over each page
for i in range(1,26):
   url = "https://www.konga.com/category/phones-tablets-5294?brand=Samsung&page=" +str(i)
   website = requests.get(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')

   name = soup.select(name_selector)
   old_price = soup.select(old_price_selector)
   new_price = soup.select(new_price_selector)
   discount = soup.select(discount_selector)

   # Combining the elements into a zipped list to be able to pull the data simultaneously
   for names, old_prices, new_prices, discounts in zip(name, old_price, new_price, discount):
      dic = {"Phone Names": names.getText(),"New Prices": new_prices.getText(),"Old Prices": old_prices.getText(),"Discounts": discounts.getText()}
      data.append(dic)

   data
```

Comment: for i in range(1, 26) will set i from 1 to 25. for i in range(1, 27) will set i from 1 to 26

Comment: At first, check your `print(website.content)` if expected data is available. If not, evaluate what could be the reason for this and if you stuck, search for or ask a question with exact this focus.

Comment: Data is being pulled via a POST request from a GraphQL endpoint ... so you have some legwork to do. There are quite a few questions on this forum pertaining to scraping GraphQL endpoints. It's doable, it's not even that hard - just inspect Dev Tools - Network tab, find the endpoint, find the payload, check the other answers on the subject, and you'll be alright.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the below and it works for me getting 40 name values.

I wasn't able to get the values using beautiful soup but directly through selenium.

If you decide to use Chrome and PyCharm as I have then:

Open Chrome. Click on three dots near top right. Click on Settings then About Chrome to see the version of your Chrome. Download the corresponding driver [here.](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) Save the driver in the PyCharm PATH folder

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Assigning column names using class_ names
name_selector = "af885_1iPzH"

# Looping over each page
for i in range(1, 27):
    url = "https://www.konga.com/category/phones-tablets-5294?brand=Samsung&page=" +str(i)
    driver.get(url)

    xPath = './/*[@class="' + name_selector + '"]'
    name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xPath)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @Cyrus. Please do you know how I can use selenium and Chrome driver in Jupyter Notebook, I have researched but I have not gotten valuable solution. Thank you again

Comment: Sorry I have no exposure to Jupyter Notebook yet. If my answer has solved your problem, then please accept it as the correct answer ? You can do so by clicking the large "V" tick at the top of my answer.

Comment: I followed your code using Pycharm and tried **print(name)**  but I got this output:             `[]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4e1ee70b706d8b3181bd8d48b0cffd12", element="61f189cb-30c7-44fa-8320-5abfc140aa53")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4e1ee70b706d8b3181bd8d48b0cffd12", element="a3e0938a-b181-41c7-b319-606b93d7d6fc")>` The output was longer than this but i had to cut it to fit in the comment box. Then i tried **print(name.text)** but i got an attribute error saying "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text' "

Comment: If you edit your question, it will allow you to include the whole of the error message. No idea why it works for me but not for you. Perhaps you can update your question with your amended code.